# django web project - connected with https. Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed

Tags: django

There was no problem when connecting to the http server.

If you log in from the web server after connecting to https, the following error works:

In login.html {% csrf_token %} is written

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

More information is available with DEBUG=True.
```

Is there any way to enable this when DEBUG= False?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS in settings.py
such as:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://google.com"]
```

Replace `https://google.com` above with your own domain.